# Can flyway be used to export DB schema to a git repo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, flyway

Let's say I want to schedule the export of the schema of a MS SQL Server database incrementally (whenever changes happen or at least periodically like once nightly) and store it in version control like git, is this doable with Flyway Community edition.

The idea being I want to track the schema level changes to a database over time along with the front end application code changes. The said front end application's code is also being tracked in git.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of flyway is you make the schema changes with version scripts which are stored in git. In dev you can 'migrate' often and when you deploy to the next environment along it will deploy everything that hasn't been migrated yet. So no, flyway cannot export your schema, but if you work with flyway, you shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

The opensource version of Flyway does not help you with script generation. It's just a mechanism for ensuring that you can successfully deploy the migration scripts, in order. It does a great job at that, but that's all it does. Script generation is on you.

There is an Enterprise version of Flyway. With that, you get an additional tool called [Flyway Desktop](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/getting-started-with-flyway-desktop?product=flyway-desktop). That will help you generate the code and get it into source control.